# Why adding one more parameter to the Stored Procedure makes it very slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a SP with 5 parameters `@State,@StartDate,@EndDate,@AsOfDate,@SICCode`. If I execute SP and supply parameters it returns the data ~ 1 sec. 
Then if I add another parameter  `@Coverage` then it takes ~ 17 sec to execute it.

I looked at the Cache Plan with and without `@Coverage` parameter and it seems like it looks the same.
I used tuning adviser and created all possible indexes.

If I run same code as `SELECT` statement and provide the same values as parameters in `WHERE` clause - then I got the result for ~1 sec. 
So why only when I add this exact one parameter @Coverage it slows down performance so significantly?

If it a parameter sniffing then how can I be sure that it is? Is any ways to check?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EarningPlazaCommercial] 
@State varchar(50),
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@AsOfDate datetime,
@SICCode nvarchar(max),
@Coverage varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #PolicyNumbers  (PolicyNumber varchar(50))
    INSERT INTO #PolicyNumbers SELECT  PolicyNumber FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet WHERE SICCode IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@SICCode,','))-- ('0161','0173','0179','0181','0191','0722','0752','0761','0782','1440','1441','1442','1521','1522','161','1611','1629','1711','172','1731','1742') 
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_PolicyNumbers_PolicyNumber ON #PolicyNumbers(PolicyNumber) 
    ; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
       SELECT Cast(@AsOfDate AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
    ), policy_data AS (
        SELECT
            PolicyNumber,
            Coverage
    ,       Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate
    ,       Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate
    ,       WrittenPremium
    --,     --State
            FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet piwp
            WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber) 
                    AND Coverage IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@Coverage,','))
                    AND State IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@State,','))     
    )...
```

And this is the data I am working with:

[image]

Comment: do you have any index on the coverage column?

Comment: Does [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) help?

Comment: It looks like you are doing 2 function splits in your `Where` clause. Split the strings into temp tables at the top of your stored proc and then reference the temp tables instead.

Comment: M.Ali
Yes, I have index on the Coverage column.  Thanks

Comment: What does your StringOfStringsToTable function look like? I have a feeling that is going to be the culprit in your performance woes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are working on string. Without indexes. With complicate logic.

You should organize your columns (make `database normalization`). You indexes.

You should use set theory instead of working with composed strings.

If you don't want to much change your qry, so change execution plan with rewriting to derivated qry.

```
select * 
from (select ...) t 
where Coverage (SELECT KeyCol FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@Coverage,','))
```

Pleas, try avoid use of `*`.

Comment: I tried. It didnt help unfortunately. But what do you mean by working on string? And "use set theory instead of working with composed strings"?
Thanks

Comment: For whole set split your strings into one table (key; string). For second set split strings into one table (key2; string2)... Join whole sets with your decomposed tables together. You can use views also. But you should decompose your string first. Try run your procedure with option recompile.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I got it work by putting everything in #TempTable using all parameters. Then `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber)`
Getting the result in  ~1 sec.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber) 
                    AND Coverage IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@Coverage,','))
                    AND State IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@State,','))
```

I inserted all policy numbers filtered by all parameters in a `#PolicyNumbers`
then used

```
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber)
```

The result displays in ~1sec